# Safely using a StreamReader with HttpContent.ReadAsStreamAsync() without closing the underlying stream

Tags: streamreader, httpcontent

I have multiple Attribute classes which need to access the data in an `HttpContent` (which is in an `HttpActionContext`'s `HttpRequstMessage`) but I am having issues deciding on the best way to do it. I considered using the `ReadAsStringAsync` method on the `HttpContent`, but it seems that I need access to the `Stream` to first set the position to 0.

The naive way seems to just wrap a `StreamReader` around the base stream with a `using` statement like so:

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
  string rawJson;
  using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(actionContext.Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result))
  {
    streamReader.BaseStream.Position = 0;
    rawJson = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
  }
  // etc
}
```

This works well for the first attribute that executes but every subsequent attribute that executes throws an exception on `actionContext.Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync()` because it was disposed.

## Here are alternative methods that work, but I'd really like to know the optimal method of doing this.

## 1: Wrap a `StreamReader` around the base stream and never dispose it.

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
  StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(actionContext.Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result);
  streamReader.BaseStream.Position = 0;
  string rawJson = streamReader.ReadToEnd();     
  // etc
}
```

This works well for every attribute but **I worry that I might be leaking memory** by not disposing the `StreamReader`.

## 2: Copy the base stream to a `MemoryStream` and wrap that with a `StreamReader`.

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    Stream s = actionContext.Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result;
    s.Position = 0;
    s.CopyTo(memoryStream);
    string rawJson;
    using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(memoryStream))
    {
      streamReader.BaseStream.Position = 0;
      rawJson = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    }
  // etc
}
```

This works well for every attribute but **is a lot of code and might be inefficient**.

## 3: Set the base stream's position to 0 then call `ReadAsStringAsync`.

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
  actionContext.Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result.Position = 0;
  string rawJson = actionContext.Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
  // etc
}
```

This works well for every attribute but **might be less efficient**.

So, is there an optimal way to do this without leaking memory?

Answer (score 0):

Use the stream reader that leaves the stream open - because you don't take ownership of the stream, it is still owned in the scope of the HTTP action content.

```
public StreamReader (System.IO.Stream stream, System.Text.Encoding encoding, bool detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks, int bufferSize, bool leaveOpen);
```

[Constructor with the option to leave the stream open](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_StreamReader__ctor_System_IO_Stream_System_Text_Encoding_System_Boolean_System_Int32_System_Boolean_)

Also use of .Result to complete asynchronous calls in a sync context is risky due to possible deadlocks. Try to refactor your methods as asynchronous instead.